# showing post description fading in on hover

Tags: jquery

Right now I have the following code set up:

```
$(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.thumbnail').fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('.description').fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
    $('.description').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.description').fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('.thumbnail').fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
});
```

With this html:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="description">
    <p>content here</p>
</div>
```

It works good but I'd like the thumbnail to fade slightly with a black background so the thumbnail image still shows slightly. Right now, the background just shows white when I hover over it. How can I go about doing this? Also, is there a better way to write the code, perhaps using something other than mouseenter? I'm still a beginner with jQuery so it's all new to me.

Something like this would be ideal: http://www.brandingdirection.co.uk/

Comment: can you please post this in jfiddle? :)

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/UCy4T/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- edited to tidy up ---

Final code demo at

Text link version: http://jsfiddle.net/thewebdes/LDs6C/

Image link version: http://jsfiddle.net/thewebdes/jY2e2/1/

HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://chuvachienes.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/hello.jpg" width="200"/>

    <div class="description">
        <p>content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.thumbnail { background: #000; width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden; }
.description { display: none; position: relative; top: -190px; left: 10px; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; }
```

JS

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
    $('.thumbnail img').stop(true,true).fadeTo(400, 0.2);
    $('.description').stop(true,true).fadeIn(400);
}, function() {
    $('.thumbnail img').stop(true,true).fadeTo(400, 1);
    $('.description').stop(true,true).fadeOut(400);
});
```

To make links, either link the pieces of text you want to link from or if you want the whole block to link, link the image. If linking the whole block, to avoid confusion you should add `cursor: pointer` to your `.description p` as otherwise you'll just get the text select cursor instead while you're hovering over the text.

Comment: I've noticed that if you run your mouse through the image back and forth real fast, it fades in and out the amount of times I ran my mouse through it. Is there a way to have it so it only fades to black once while the mouse is on the image?

Comment: Hi John. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/thewebdes/44Sf3/. All it needed was `.stop(true,true)` during each of the hover states. Sorry about that!

Comment: Scott, thanks for your help on this. Sorry to bother you again but if you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/44Sf3/1/, you'll notice I updated the content with more text. However, now when I hover over the box, it flickers on and off as I move my mouse over the text. Any ideas on how this can be avoided?

Comment: I don't remember putting that extra content in but if flagged up a problem with it, that's for sure! Nothing like testing is there...! I'll take a look and let you know.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I'm the one that put that extra content in there by the way.

Comment: Yeah, sorted now. Changed the hover element from `.thumbnail img` to just `.thumbnail`. I think we _might_ be there now!

Comment: It's a pleasure mate. Just tidied my answer up to make it a little more followable now!

Comment: Er...sorry just one more question. Is there a way to make links in the content clickable?

Comment: No problem, I've added it to the bottom of the answer. There are a couple of ways you can do this, as you'll see. Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood what you wrote but I tried adding in a link (update here: http://jsfiddle.net/44Sf3/16/) and I still can't seem to click it.

Comment: Ok, no probs. I've changed the way the text is positioned. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/thewebdes/LDs6C/. My answer above has changed to reflect this as well. There are now two versions linked to on jsfiddle, one for text links, one for a link from the whole block.

Comment: No probs. Hope it works for whatever project you're using it on.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/UCy4T/2/

```
$(function() {

  var animationspeed = 500;

  $('.thumbnail').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').fadeOut(animationspeed);
    $('.description').fadeIn(animationspeed);
  });
  $('.description').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.description').fadeOut(animationspeed);
    $('.thumbnail').fadeIn(animationspeed);
  });
});
```

Added a variable for your animation speed. also you need to change your css to set the elements to the same position and dimensions:

```
.description {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.thumbnail {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, corroded.

Comment: no prob, i realized you wanted the black background also. sory about that